# Flutter show download failed with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException after downloading 100%

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to make a wallpaper app to download images but it shows download failed when it completes download with error Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority. I am downloading with flutter-downloader package.
Thanks.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority
sagarrawatuk.fotoApp.flutter_downloader.provider**

```
class _ImagePathState extends State<ImagePath> {
String localPath;

Future<String> get localpath async {
final result = await Permission.storage.request();
if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
  final localPath =
      (await findLocalPath()) + Platform.pathSeparator + 'Download';
  final savedDir = Directory(localPath);
  bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
  if (!hasExisted) {
    savedDir.create();
  }
  return localPath;
  } else
  return null;
  }

  Future<String> findLocalPath() async {
  final directory = Platform.isAndroid
    ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
    : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   return directory.path;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: myColor,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
          onPressed: () async => DownloadTask(
              taskId: await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                  url: widget.imgPath,
                  savedDir: await localpath,
                  showNotification: true)))
      ],
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
       child: Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Hero(
                tag: widget.imgPath, child: Image.network(widget.imgPath)),
          ),
         ],
        ),
       ),
     ),
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add provider in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

See docs https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader#android-integration